# $ \mathcal{E}(X) $ generates $ B(X) $

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

> Let $ X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ and let $ \mathcal{E}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ a generator of the borel sigma algebra $ \mathcal{B}^n $ which means $ \sigma(\mathcal{E})=\mathcal{B}^n $. Then the set
> $$ \mathcal{E}(X):\{E\cap X:E\in \mathcal{E}\} $$
> is a generator of $ B(X):=\{B\cap X: B\in \mathcal{B}^n\} $ on $ X $ which means $ \sigma(\mathcal{E}(X))=B(X) $.

For ,,$ \subseteq $".Show at first $ \mathcal{E}(X)\subseteq B(X) $. Let $ M\in \mathcal{E}(X) $ be arbitrary. Then it is $ M=E\cap X $ for one set $ E\in \mathcal{E} $. Because $ \mathcal{E} $ generates $ \mathcal{B}^n $ then it follows $ E\in \mathcal{E}\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{E})=\mathcal{B}^n $, so $ E\in \mathcal{B}^n $ such that $ M=E\cap X\in B(X) $. This implies $ \mathcal{E}(X)\subseteq B(X) $ and furthermore $ \sigma(\mathcal{E}(X))\subseteq \sigma(B(X))=B(X) $.

For ,,$ \supseteq $". Show this inclusion by the principle of good sets. Define the set
$$ \mathcal{G}:=\{A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n: A\cap X\in \sigma(\mathcal{E}(X))\}. $$
1.) Show $ \mathcal{G} $ is a sigma algebra on $ \mathbb{R}^n $

2.) Show $ \mathcal{E}\subseteq \mathcal{G} $.

At 1.) I already get stuck how to show $ \mathbb{R}^n\in \mathcal{G} $. I consider $ \mathbb{R}^n\cap X=X $. But why is $ X\in \sigma(\mathcal{E}(X)) $ ?
And get a similar problem how to show $ A\in \mathcal{G}\Rightarrow A^c\in \mathcal{G} $.